# Utility class to return GPS location in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, gps, cllocationmanager

In my app I need the location of the user several times, so I created an utility class to get the coordinates. This is not working as intended, since I want to call a function to directly return the coordinates, but it doesn't work since it's dine asynchronously. I want, in my viewcontroller, to be able to call it as a singleton, like this:

```
coords = GPSUtil.sharedInstance.getCoordinates()
```

With use of the following function:

```
public func getCoordinates() -> CLLocation {
    // return the CLLocation here.
}

public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]
    initialLocation = latestLocation as! CLLocation
}
```

At the moment my locationManager just assigns the CLLocation to a property, but I actually want the above method to return it. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should add a `var` to your utility class, like so:

```
class GPSUtil {
    var latestLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0) //initial init

    public func getCoordinates() -> CLLocation {
        return self.latestLocation
    }

    public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        self.latestLocation = locations[locations.count - 1]
    }
}
```

Comment: I belive I tried that, and it seems it returns before the location has been dertermined? Since it takes some time from calling locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() till it determines.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't comment on why it might not be working. Specifically, I don't know how you are having `didUpdateLocations` called.

Comment: I believe it is called automatically when calling locationManager.startUpdatingLocation(), and the problem seems to be, that if I just return the property it doesn't get assigned before later on. So I believe I have to wait until the property is assigned in the locationManager-function, I just don't know how.

Comment: Ok, in that case I'd suggest using a delegate via protocol so you can pass back to the delegate the new location when it becomes available, or have as a variable a closure that is called when new location available.

Comment: Can you hint me a bit? With a simple example or link to a resource? Much appreciated mate.

Comment: I considered using a completion-block, but I can't figure out how to. The problem seems rather simple, if I just return the coordinates in my function, the coordinates doesn't get assigned yet, so I obviously want to wait until the coordinates are set.